# Not able to understand .NET clr & coreclr

Tags: .net, .net-core

I was trying to understand the difference between .NET core's runtime clr & coreclr. In order to understand it, I wrote a small application and tried to capture outputs by changing `runtime` and `framework dependencies`(No code change).

Results I got as shown in screenshot.

[image: Runime Vs Framework Dependency]

However, I couldn't understand much than `clr` is compatible with **`dnx451`** and `coreclr` with **`dnxcore50`** & backword compatible with RC1 tools (dnu & dnx).

Basically, code will be run fine if `runtime` set to **`coreclr`** and framework is set to **`dnx451`** or **`dnxcore50`**.

Am I confusing myself with something simple or need to understand something more which I am missing?

Comment: .NET programmers are not typically very used to the open source ways.  The project is evolving fast, stuff gets quickly outdated or obsolete, there are plenty of bugs and mixing and matching is a recipe for trouble.  The only real shot you'd have at knowing when you should stop using something like dnx/dnu is to be actively involved in the project.  They expect you to file a bug report if you encounter a problem.  That's work, if you don't have the time then the best strategy is to wait until they are done.

Comment: @HansPassant, I agree to your point, as there are daily builds, RC1, RC2, Preview builds. Not sure which works well, which is compatible with frameworks & also there are structural changes too, e.g. `project.json` changes a log compare to rc1 & rc2. 
**More interested to understand (runtimes) `clr` Vs `coreclr`**, understanding dnvm, dnu,dnx tools are getting discarded with rc2 and going forward. 

Also, if any source to keep updated on daily/periodically changes happening in  .net core world?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `dotnet` does not support changing the runtime the same way as dnvm/dnu/dnx did. From [*Migrating from DNX to .NET Core CLI*](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html#main-changes-in-the-tooling):

> Given this, the DNVM install features are not needed. But what about the runtime selection features?
>
> You reference a runtime in your `project.json` by adding a package of a certain version to your dependencies. With this change, your application will be able to use the new runtime bits.